# In a box there are $R$ red pens and $B$ blue pens. What is the probability that you need to pick up a pen $3$ times?

Tags: probability, algorithms

In a box there are $R$ red pens and $B$ blue pens. Pens are randomly selected, one at a time, until a red one is obtained. Assume that each selected pen is replaced before the next one is drawn.

(a) what is the probability that you need to pick up a pen $3$ times?

(b) what is the probability that you need to pick up a pen at least $4$ times?

My work: for (a) would it be as easy as $3*(b/(b+a))$? Otherwise I'm quite confused as to how to approach this.

for (b) $(b/(b+a)) * ((b+a)-b)$?

Comment: For the first part, assuming that $b=B$ and $a=R$... say, $b=10$ and $a=1$ then your formula gives $3\times \frac {10}{11}=\frac {30}{11}$ which is not a possible probability.

Comment: Hint:  for the first part, all you need is that the first two draws be Blue.  Probabilities of multiple simultaneous (independent) events multiply...they don't add.

Comment: Would it then be (b/(b+a)) * (b/(b+a))?

Comment: It would.  Can you handle the other part the same way?

Comment: (b/(b+a)) * (b/(b+a)) * (b/(b+a))?

Comment: More commonly written $\left(\frac b{b+a}\right)^3$, but absolutely correct.

Comment: a) Presumably need to pick up three times means blue, blue, red. Then we get $\left(\frac{B}{B+R}\right)^2 \cdot \frac{R}{B+R}$.

Comment: The comment of @AndréNicolas is very relevant here.  I interpreted the question to mean "at least three times" but, given that the second part adds the "at least" in, one could sensibly argue that the first part meant "exactly three times", in which case the answer would indeed be $(\frac b{b+a})^2\times \frac a{a+b}$.  This is a common ambiguity...always best to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability of getting a red pen at one single pick is a/(a+b)

(a) answer = $(b/(a+b))^2$  * a/(a+b)

(b) let p(n) denotes the probability that you need n picks to get the first red. so p(n) = $(b/(a+b))^{n-1}$  * a/(a+b)

Hence, answer = 1 - (p(1) + p(2) + p(3))